# ctypes return array of strings std::vector<std::string>>

Tags: python, c++, c, string, ctypes

I am able to return a string after it is converted to a `char*`.

```
import ctypes
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.

libname = "c:\temp\debug_api_lib.dll"
c_lib = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(libname)


class Gilad(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        c_lib.menu_function_new.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int]
        c_lib.menu_function_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

        c_lib.get_mac_address_new.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
        c_lib.get_mac_address_new.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

        c_lib.get_otp_data_new.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
        c_lib.get_otp_data_new.restype = (ctypes.c_char_p * 3)

        self.obj = c_lib.menu_function_new(host, port)

    def get_mac_address(self):
        return c_lib.get_mac_address_new(self.obj)

    def get_otp_data(self):
        return c_lib.get_otp_data_new(self.obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = "11.11.11.11".encode('utf-8')
    t = Gilad(host, 21)
    print(t.get_mac_address())
    otp_data: object = t.get_otp_data()
    for i in otp_data: //the issue is here
        print(i)
```

Here is my cpp code wrapped with c-style:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) menu_function* menu_function_new(char * host, int port)
    {
        return new menu_function(host, port);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) char* get_mac_address_new(menu_function* menu_function)
    {
        std::string res_string = menu_function->get_mac_address();
        char* res = new char[res_string.size()];
        res_string.copy(res, res_string.size(), 0);
        res[res_string.size()] = '\0';
        return res;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) char** get_otp_data_new(menu_function* menu_function)
    {
        int num = 3;
        std::vector<std::string> res_string = menu_function->get_otp_data();
        char** res = (char**)malloc(num * sizeof(char**));
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            res[i] = (char*)malloc(res_string[i].size());
            res_string[i].copy(res[i], res_string[i].size(), 0);
            res[i][res_string[i].size()] = '\0';
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I can see in `res` the 3 strings being copied correctly, but when printing in python I get: `b'\xa0y\xa4P\x12\x01'`

I guess I am printing the pointers.

Comment: Try `c_lib.get_otp_data_new.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)`

Comment: @Artyer YES!!! thank you!

Comment: Not that it makes a difference since sizeof(char**) == sizeof(char*), but your malloc line should technically be `char** res = (char**)malloc(num * sizeof(char*));`

Comment: this is C++ code, not C code  Please delete the C tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is returning a `char**`, and you've told Python that it is returning a `char*[3]` (an array of 3 `char*` pointers, not a pointer itself), so the returned value isn't being interpreted properly by ctypes.

Change the return type to `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)`, or alternatively change your program to return something that has the same size as `char*[3]`, like `std::array<char*, 3>` or `struct otp_data { char *one, *two, *three; };` (which would be 1 less malloc since you can return this by value)

Comment: it works but I get an exception when I finish the for loop 
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF839EE06BB (_ctypes.pyd) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000FDFDFDFD.

Comment: @Gilad The pointer doesn't have size information attached. Instead of ``for i in otp_data: # use `i` ``, ``for i in range(3): # use `otp_data[i]` ``

Comment: you are correct again, is there a good way to pass the size and the pointer back?

Comment: If the size is not always 3, you have to return it somehow from the dll. You can change it to return a structure like `struct size_and_data { int num; char** res_string };` and change the restype to `class size_and_data(ctypes.Structure): _fields_ = [("num", ctypes.c_int), ("data", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))]`, and using `for i in range(otp_data.num): print(otp_data.data[i])`. If the size is always 3, you can return `std::array<char*, 3>` and change the restype to `(ctypes.c_char_p * 3)`, which does have the size attatched.

Comment: C linkage function cannot return C++ class 'std::array<char *,2>' can't use std::array it is c++

Comment: @Gilad It can, you will just have a hard time naming it in C code, but you can totally pretend it's a plain C array in python. But if you are using it with C code, `struct opt_data { char* data[3]; }` can be returned instead, which can be put in a C header file